# How to use a really custom repository without Spring intervention using Spring JPA

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I want to create a customer repository to find entity based on child entities (which has its own repository). 
If I use the schema of CustomSomethingInterface + CustomSomethingImp and then extend the Something repository with the CustomerSomething interface, the JPA crashes because it tries to implement the methods on the custom repository but cannot find my reference field. How can I create really custom methods with no spring intervention ?

Comment: The schema is `CustomSomethingInterface` + `CustomSomethingInterfaceImpl`. The naming is important.

Comment: yes it was just a typo here, anyway question remains,

Comment: Then how about showing us what you do with some actual code instead of describing something you didn't do with vague prose? Also, stack traces, please.